# When I run react-native run-android I'm getting this error

Tags: php, android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

When I run react-native run-android I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development tools installed.

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Comment: Please provide additional information (e.g code to reproduce this error)  for others to look into it.

Comment: Don't run the command within `Android Studio` because it requires the command to be run as `Administrator`. So, open `cmd as administrator` and run the command!